# Node-Webkit won't open file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-webkit, fs

First I'd like to say thanks for taking the time to read this.
I am trying to open a JSON file that is in the following directory structure:

```
#--> Root Folder
   --> App.exe
  #--> Configuration
      ---> JSON File
```

So I used the Code:

```
var ConfigFile = "./Configuration/JSON.json";
```

Followed by:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file_content = fs.readFileSync(ConfigFile);
var content = JSON.parse(file_content);
   // Manipulate the Data
```

For some odd reason, Node-Webkit seems to be looking for the folder in a Temp Directory located in:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\nw9740_14956\Configuration

The file is not there, and thus in the Console I get the following Error:

> Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\nw9740_14956\Configuration\JSON.json'

I am running Windows (as you can tell), and I would like for **fs** to pull the file from the Folder (Configuration) that is adjacent to the app.exe.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this once, so I may be wrong, but it looks like you're bundling your app content into the exe?  If you do this, node-webkit will extract the app contents into the `%TEMP%` folder and then run the content from there.

Try checking the command line arguments to see if `arg[0]` will point you to the actual node-webkit exe that's running the app.  From there, you should be able to construct a path to your configuration data.